# Put someone in a class/make someone join a class

Tags: word-usage

X's mother got her child enrolled in a personality development class because she was very shy,so what should be used:

> She put X in a personality development class.
>
> She made X join a personality development class.

What should be used :"put in" or "join" or either of them can be used?

Comment: Why not use "enrolled" as the verb?

Comment: But I wanted to use either of those options. @Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work.

> Made **Variable** Join **Variable2**
>
> Put **Variable** in **Variable2**

As far as Concerned, either would work fine as long as you worded it right

Answer (score 0):

Either of these will work, but the two sentences are slightly different. If you say that the mother 'made' the child join the class, there is a sense that the child did not want to join the class. The word 'made' in this case is like saying she compelled the child to join or forced the child to join the class against the child's will. The other option is more neutral. if the mother 'put' the child in the class there is no indication that the child was not in agreement with the mother's action.